# Hi I am confused how to solve this question

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]

Hi I have been trying this question for days but cannot get to the answer. This question seems to be a lot tough. I tried many ways but cannot reach the answer. It will be a humble request if anyone solves this.  question has been attached as a link above.

I have tried this question by simplifying the root terms , I used $\;\sqrt2+1=\dfrac1{\sqrt2-1}\;.$

But nothing came out i think this is a mixed up of two series .

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is also an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: You should write what you have tried, otherwise your question will be closed by moderators very soon.

Comment: *Hint:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the binomial expansion of
$$\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{2\sqrt{2}}} + \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{2\sqrt{2}}}\right)^{64}$$

You can simplify this and write it like:
$$\left(\frac{e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 2}}{2}\right)^{64}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: yess thanks i got the answer as b